# c++ implementing clock to measure execution time

Tags: c++, timer

I have written a program in c++ and am trying to measure the time it takes to execute completely

```
int main (int argc, char**argv){
    clock_t tStart = clock();
    //doing my program's work here
    printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

My issue is that it will always print out 0.00s for the execution time. Could this be due to using multiple pthreads in my program (my program uses pthread_join to make sure that all threads have completed executing so I don't think this should be an issue)?

edit: //doing program's work =...

```
for(i = 0;i<4;i++){
    err = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, print, NULL); 
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
}

void *print(void *data){
    printf("hello world");
}
```

Comment: clock() gets CPU time not wall-clock. Is this what you want?

Comment: Hm changed to using time_t tStart and time_t tEnd and used difftime(tEnd,tStart); which works. Not sure why CPU time would come back as 0 anyways though. Either should work I am just using to see if my program using threads is actually faster than my similar program without threads

Comment: because maybe the main thread sleeps while the other threads execute so you don't use any CPU time on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("Time taken: %.2fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

All three of your arithmetic operands are integers, so you perform integer division and get `0`.

Cast either the LHS or the RHS of the `/` symbol to a floating-point type. And run your code more times! Your benchmark is useless if it measures just a single run (which is pretty evident since you got `0`, not `1` or like `300` or something).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what is in `//doing my program's work here`. If it is kicking off other threads, then you will definitely need to wait or poll to get a time. Show the code to get more help! In a similar situation I was in recently, however, it turned out that my code was actually running in less than 0.01 seconds.

Comment: I am definitely kicking off other threads however as long as I am using pthread_join on all threads after I create them then it shouldn't matter should it? beacuse they will wait and join before the code ever executes the print clock statement? or is my understanding incorrect? (obviously it is haha)